# What's the easiest way to transfer files back and forth between a Windows 10 host OS running Hyper-V and a guest OS running Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: virtualization

I tried using the "Connect to Server" feature in Nautilus to access a shared folder on the Windows host.  It allows me to copy files from the Ubuntu guest to the Windows host; but it doesn't work in the other direction, i.e. Nautilus won't display the contents of the shared folder on the host.   I don't know enough about network shares to troubleshoot what's wrong; and my web searches haven't yielded a better solution.
Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: Both, the usage of Hyper-V, and creating network shares with write permission on a Windows host is nothing Ubuntu can do about.

Comment: Have you tried below answer?  Anything wrong/not working???  **:/**

Answer (score 4):

The easiest *and fastest* way to transfer files between two machines regardless of their OS/configuration/hardware/connectivity is best done with [NitroShare](https://nitroshare.net/downloads/) as it doesn't need any infrastructure and is easy to install and blindingly fast.  It also runs on everything: [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/nitroshare), [Windows](http://windows.quickmediasolutions.com/nathan), ...

To install NitroShare, just download it from the above link and install, disable any firewalls and a small icon now shows up in the menu bar:

[image: Nitroshare Menu bar Icon]

(do these steps on both VMs)

On one computer, click the NitroShare icon and click <kbd>Send Directory</kbd> to send entire directories or <kbd>Send Files</kbd> send individual files!

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**